# I can't access Stack Overflow with Windows 11 + Wifi 6 router + Organization proxies

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, router, proxy

I am unable to access stackoverflow.com when using a modern router supporting Wi-Fi 6 via mainstream browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome).

I can access all Stack Exchange sites, such as [superuser](https://superuser.com/), [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) etc. for all following combinations:

|  | cURL | Via Browser in Ofc laptop (Windows) | Via Browser in a Ubuntu VM in Ofc laptop | Via Browser Personal Laptop | Mobile Device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Network 1 ADSL | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Network 2 Wi-Fi 6 | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |

I am unable to rule out common issues:

- Custom firewall rules in official laptop for browsers, because works with Network 1.
- Issue with Network 2 router configuration, because works with personal laptop and mobile device and even via curl in official laptop.

traceroutes and pings are working as expected (also supported by the fact that I am able to access stackoverflow.com via curl).

From this [Cloudflare community discussion](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/some-websites-that-use-cloudflare-are-unreachable/576068/7), I installed [httptoolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/) which sets up a local proxy and a self-singed certification. It also configures a browser window to serve traffic via this proxy. Interestingly, I can access stackoverflow.com on Chrome + Windows 11 + httptoolkit local proxy.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot tell because of the firewall customizations, but for sure and for 3 years, Stack Overflow works fine with native Windows 11 Pro.